# using a wx.Simplebook giving me exit code 3221225477

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to wrap my head around using [`wx.Simplebook`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Simplebook.html?highlight=wx.simplebook#wx.Simplebook), and as far as I can tell I've basically copied the python demo, but obviously am missing something vital.

This example should be a [`wx.Frame`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Frame.html?highlight=wx.frame#wx.Frame) with two [`wx.Buttons`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Button.html?highlight=wx.button#wx.Button) on the left and the `wx.Simplebook` on the right. The two buttons should switch between the pages of the book.

```py
import wx


class MainPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, None, 1, title = "NOTEBOOK", pos= wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 320,400 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        buttonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pagesSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(buttonSizer,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
        mainSizer.Add(pagesSizer,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
        page1Button = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Page 1",wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,0)
        page2Button = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Page 2",wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,0)
        buttonSizer.Add(page1Button,1,0)
        buttonSizer.Add(page2Button,1,0)
        book = MainPage.BookTest(self)
        pagesSizer.Add(book,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Layout()

    class BookTest (wx.Simplebook):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            wx.Simplebook.__init__(self,parent)
            page1=MainPage.Page1(self)
            page2=MainPage.Page2(self)
            self.AddPage(page1,"")
            self.AddPage(page2,"")

    class Page1 (wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            t=wx.StaticText(self,-1,"THIS IS PAGE 1")
            sizer.Add(t,1,wx.EXPAND,0)      

    class Page2 (wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            t=wx.StaticText(self,-1,"THIS IS PAGE 2")
            sizer.Add(t,1,wx.EXPAND,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MainPage(None)
    frm.Centre()
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Half the time the build pauses, and nothing is shown (although I get a 'Finished in 2.0 seconds' message), the other half of the time i get error code 3221225477.

if you # the line `pagesSizer.Add(book,1,wx.EXPAND)`, the frame opens as planned, but obviously without the simplebook.
Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks,

Sundown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your code is missing just a few details. First, the indentation of the classes is wrong. They should all start in the first column. The code suggests (at least to me) that you are thinking about `BookTest`, `Page1` and `Page2` as subclasses of `MainPage`. But this is not the correct way to think about it. They are all independent classes and you will use in `MainPage` and instance of `BookTest` and `BookTest` will use an instance of `Page1` and an instance of `Page2`.

Changing this leads to change the line `book = MainPage.BookTest(self)` to `book = BookTest(self)`

The second problem is that you need to keep track of parent/child relationship for your widgets because this helps a lot to correctly display them. Therefore, you need to pass the `parent` argument when starting the `wx.Simplebook` and `wx.Panel` widget in `BookTest` and `Page1` and `Page2`.

Here is the code,

```
import wx


class MainPage (wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, None, 1, title = "NOTEBOOK", pos= wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 320,400 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        buttonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pagesSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(buttonSizer,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
        mainSizer.Add(pagesSizer,1,wx.EXPAND,0)
        page1Button = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Page 1",wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,0)
        page2Button = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"Page 2",wx.DefaultPosition,wx.DefaultSize,0)
        buttonSizer.Add(page1Button,1,0)
        buttonSizer.Add(page2Button,1,0)
        book = BookTest(self)
        pagesSizer.Add(book,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Layout()

class BookTest (wx.Simplebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Simplebook.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        page1=Page1(self)
        page2=Page2(self)
        self.AddPage(page1,"")
        self.AddPage(page2,"")

class Page1 (wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        t=wx.StaticText(self,-1,"THIS IS PAGE 1")
        sizer.Add(t,1,wx.EXPAND,0)      

class Page2 (wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        t=wx.StaticText(self,-1,"THIS IS PAGE 2")
        sizer.Add(t,1,wx.EXPAND,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = MainPage(None)
    frm.Centre()
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```